# What do I pass into a view parameter if I want a child of the layout?

Tags: android, button, view, onclicklistener

I created a voteUp method as follows,

```
public class Voting {
public void onUpVote(View view) {
    CharSequence VoteUpId = ((TextView) ((RelativeLayout) view.getParent()).getChildAt(1)).getText();
final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
final String PUT_VOTE_UP = "URL + VoteUpId + URL";
StringRequest PostVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_UP, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        System.out.println(response + "reponse");
    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("************Answer" + error + "error");
    }
});
mrequestQueue.add(PostVoteUp);
}
```

This method takes a view object, and I also have another method as shown below in another class where I set an onClickListner

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VoteClass(What Do I pass In here??);
        }
    });
```

And I want to pass in a child of the view that is different from the button view from the same layout, and no I do not want to use the direct onClick from the xml layout to the class. So how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

implement the View.OnClickListener class and pass the view as argument like this

```
class CustomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    View view;

    public CustomClickListener(View view){
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        VoteClass(view);
    }

}
```

and then

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener(the view you want to pass));
```